# PagedList - Compiler Error CS0266 - Cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, pagedlist

I have the following problem:

```
ViewModel
public class YarnListViewModel
{
    public IPagedList<YarnFullAdmin> YarnList { get; set; }
}

Controller
var yarns = _context.YarnFullAdmins
    .Include(y => y.Brand)
    .Include(y => y.ColorProduct)
    .Where(y => y.Id > 0)
    .Select(y => new {
        y.Id,
        y.BrandId,
        y.Brand,
        y.ProductName
     });

var viewModel = new YarnListViewModel
{
    YarnList = yarns.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)
};

return View(viewModel);
```

Error on yarns.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize). If I don't do a Select in my query, it's working fine. Thanks in advance.

After @devNull comment, I made the correction:

```
var yarns = _context.YarnFullAdmins
    .Include(y => y.Brand)
    .Include(y => y.ColorProduct)
    .Where(y => y.Id > 0)
    .Select(y => new {
        Id = y.Id,
        BrandId = y.BrandId,
        Brand = y.Brand,
        ProductName = y.ProductName
     });
```

And now I have a new error on

```
var filterbranddb = _context.Brands
    .Where(b => yarns
    .Select(y => y.BrandId)
    .Contains(b.Id))
    .OrderBy(b => b.BrandName)
    .ToList()
```

The entity or complex type ... cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: You're translating to an anonymous type in the Select: `new { ...`. You probably need to select the type that the YarnList property specifies: `new YarnFullAdmin { ...`

Comment: Thank you @devNull. I'm all good now.